# Directional Moving Index (dmi) function unavailable in Pine Editor

Tags: pine-script

This line of code in Pine Editor

```
  [diplus, diminus, adx] = dmi(14, 1)
```

throws below error:

```
> Could not find function or function reference dmi
```

The intelligence suggests it's a built in fuction but it doesn't look like we can reference it in the script. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to be using v4. This works:

```
//@version=4
study("")
[diplus, diminus, adx] = dmi(14, 1)
plot(adx)
```